# How to save the output of Eclipse in a different file in every run

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver

Click on Run -> Debug Configurations…
When the Debug Configurations dialog box appears, click on the Common tab on the right side.
Under the section Standard Input and Output, check the File box.
Click on the File System button to specify the file you want to save the output to (file will be created if it does not exist).
You can click the Append box if you want to always append to the output file, or leave unchecked if you want to overwrite old output every run
Now your console output will be saved every time you run your program

I have Done that but every time i run the file is overwrite. But i want the output in different file in every run.

I am using java with Selenium Webdriver.

Comment: Rather then use System.out, it is good practice to use one of the available Java logging frameworks ([slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/), [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j), [logback](http://logging.apache.org/log4j), etc.). Most logging frameworks will allow output to be saved to a new file for each run.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that. Use eclipse internal variables.
While giving file name use eclipse internal variable and time formatting.

Enter : `${env_var:HOME}/${current_date:yyyyMM_HHmmss}_mydebugLog.txt` in file text box.
Out put files will be created in **HOME** folder with the names like **201404_113427_mydebugLog.txt** etc one for each run.

Comment: Thanks 

  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-YYYY-hhmmss");
  String dateStr = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
  System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(dateStr +"_output.txt"),true));

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by redirecting Eclipse Console output to an external file e.g. Console_Log_Output.txt. Steps are written below:

1) Open **Run** -> **Run Configurations** 
2) Find the class name which you want to run and click on it 
3) Go to **Commons** tab 
4) Under **Standard Input and Output** -> Tick the **File check-box** -> Click on **File System button** and browse the output file (Console_Log_Output.txt) 
5) Click on **Apply**.

Now you are all set. The Console output will be redirected into the selected file every time you will run the program.

Comment: This is not an answer. After each run `Console_Log_Output.txt` will be overwritten. But it is not expected.